# how to make breadcrumb in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Can Ionic provide the functionality of breadcrub .Actually I search on ionic website did not find found documentation of breadcrub .In other words how to make breadcrub in ionic .Actually I don't want to use bootstrap in my project .Actually using bootstrap it is easily achievable .But i just want to use ionic .can we make breadcrub using ionic

I found a link [image]

I want to make this type of breadcrub in ionic.can we achieve this ?
http://www.lendmeyourear.net/breadcrumb-navigation-with-css-arrows.html

I found one solution but they are using jquery .

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same. However, I found that breadcrumb is possible with AngularJS and as Ionic is based of AngularJS you can use it for sure.

Please check this link for more details https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/uiBreadcrumbs